# GitHub Gist creation and editing not working in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, github

Long story short:

I tried to create/edit GitHub Gists with

- Firefox 67.0 on Windows 10
- Firefox 67.0 on Linux Fedora
- Add-ons: NoScript, Ghostery, LastPass
- Tried with NoScript and Ghostery disabled and also with NoScript in "all shields down" mode and also with Firefox in "safe mode".

Problems:

*Creation of a Gist is arbitrary.* More often than not, the two buttons "create public gist" and "create secret gist" just stay disabled and the editor widget is "dead".

[image: dead gist editor, can't create]

Occasionally, creation works, the editor widget goes lives and displays line numbers and the editor buttons become active. But it happens annoyingly rarely.

*Editing a Gist is arbitrary.* Again, it sometimes works but currently I just get blank editor widgets that have no cursor.

Anyone else who has these problems? It may be a temporary hiccup, or maybe there is some JavaScript that Firefox doesn't like. However, a web search brings up nothing - I can't believe I am the only one stuck with this this.

Comment: Ahahahah! I retested with the latest update and I found out that it is the LastPass plugin which is the root of the problem. My earlier testing fails. I was sure I had tested in safe mode with no change in result.

Comment: I have this problem but didn't have the LastPass extension installed, nor any others - it's a fresh install. I can create Gists in Chrome, no problem. Ubuntu 18.04, Firefox 69.0.1 (64-bit).

Comment: btw I *can* create a Gist in FF 69.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10, even with LastPass installed.

Comment: btw also, going back to my Ubuntu VM where I encountered the problem, if I repeatedly press the '+' button to add a new Gist, it seemingly randomly switches between the correct behaviour - the text area widget is enabled, with a '1' in the left margin for the first line, and the wrong behaviour where the text area is disabled. As if there's a race condition between the different assets being loaded? I might log it with Mozilla... though I lost my patience with Firefox and Mozilla a long time ago (Rust is cool, though...)

Answer (score 3):

My earlier testing fails completely. I was sure I had tested in safe mode with no change in result.

However I retested with the latest Firefox update (FF 67 on Linux) and found out that it is the **LastPass plugin** which is the root of the problem. I would not have suspected that.

Disable that plugin, leaving all the others active and Gist creation and Gist editing work.

Enable that plugin and Gist creation and Gist editing work *once* after a Firefox restart. But after that, you get the unresponsive text entry widget.

Similarly, running Firefox in safe mode with all plugins disabled also fixes the "problem".

And of course, if you do this using Konqueror instead of Firefox, creation/editing work too.

Comment: It looks like on FF 68 on Windows 10 even "safe mode" (with all plugins disabled) doesn't help. (Also, I have no **LastPass** plugin at all.) :/

Comment: @RobertSkarżycki I checked again - at some point in June in worked fine, even with LastPass enabled, and I assumed someone had fixed something at LastPass or Mozilla, but now it's again not working. However, I can confirm that "safe mode" on Windows 10 *does* work.

Comment: Aha, problem is back. I noticed that NoScript often enters a zombie state whereby it thinks that restrictions are "globally disabled (dangerous)" (that's when it display a little exclamation mark) although I never told it to do so. Noticed this was on on the unresponsive gist. When into NoScript settings page (left-click on the NoScript icon, then left-click on the wrench item). "globally disabled" mark is set. Unset it. gist works after F5. Huh.

Comment: by "NoScript" you mean NoScript plugin for Firefox?

Comment: @RobertSkarżycki Yes.

Comment: It looks like having same Firefox version (68.0.1 x64) it works on one machine with Win 10 Pro Build 18362, but doesn't on Windows 10 Enterprise Build 17134. :/

Comment: Unable to paste text into the gist body in FireFox 68.0.2. I am not using LastPass

Comment: @xta Here is another one: If you have NoScript, **disable JavaScript from "githubassets.com"**. This seems to work reliably.